# Get Row Index of selected cell on specific sheet (not the one currenty selected)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Google Sheets:
I would like to get the row index (or the value inside) of the selected cell, from the specific sheet, even the sheet which is currently not in focus.
Lets say, I select a cell in sheet "A", and then move to sheet "B". From here I would like to retrieve the selected cell row index (or the value inside of that selected cell) on sheet "A".

So no method of "get Active Cell" or "get Current Cell" will work, because those methods are only refering to the currently focused sheet. I just couldn`t find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

Currently, Google Sheets API has **one and only one** Active Cell, which is contained in the active sheet. All previous cell selections are not saved.

Also, simple triggers like `onSelectionChange(e)` only takes the active cell's event object.

So the only way (for now) to get row index or values in unselected cells are defining ranges using `getRange(<range>)` and using `getValue()`.

### References:

[getActiveCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactivecell)

[Simple Triggers onSelectionChange(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee)

Comment: I thought there is something still essential still missing. Thank you Mr. Carlos M.